# Número de preguntas y respuestas por mes

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

A muchos nos puede interesar cómo va la comunidad y en el sitio de **StackExchange Data** no pude encontrar querys de buena calidad, ya que en mi humilde opinión los querys y rutinas que hay para hacer lo mismo están pésimamente construidos.

Alguien tiene un query decente para ello?

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388/sede-bug-de-query-o-de-sitio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si a alguien le sirve he creado este query en **StackExchange** para obtener el performance de preguntas y respuestas por mes.

Aunque lo considero mucho mejor que cualquier otra cosa que pude encontrar en  **StackExchange Data** puede que el mio no esté perfecto, cualquier aporte es bienvenido.

### [Number of Questions and Answers per Month in a given YYYY/MM range](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/425430/number-of-questions-and-answers-per-month-in-a-given-yyyy-mm-range?start=%272015%2F10%27+&end=%272016%2F01%27)

Y estos son los resultados a la fecha (2016/01/19) incluyendo el parcial de Enero

[image: preguntas y respuestas a 2016/01/19]

Comment: No me parece apropiado usar ParentID para distinguir en las publicaciones cuales son preguntas y respuestas ya que además están los wikis de etiquetas. En su lugar usar PostTypeId = 1 para preguntas y PostTypeId = 2 para respuestas. Véase http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/289691

Comment: Asi es lo mejorare esta tarde

Comment: @JuanK, los resultados de esta consulta son incorrectos. En diciembre definitivamente no se publicó 924 preguntas. Mirá [mi respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/403/21).

Comment: @jachguate he modificado el query para hacerlo utilizando el `PostTypeId` y ahora las cifras coinciden con las tuyas, mil gracias

Answer (score 3):

Creo que lo que se busca es esto:

http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/425073/question-and-answer-count-per-month

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Entre los queries destacados está

[Total Questions and Answers per Month for the last 12](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/6134/total-questions-and-answers-per-month-for-the-last-12) el cual incluye como descripción

> Total number of questions and answers for the last 12 months (in 30 day chunks)

Dicho query estaba dando datos incorrectos ya que incluída entre las publicaciones contadas otras publicaciones además de preguntas y respuestas.

Lo [edité](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/revision/425031/541530/total-questions-and-answers-per-month-for-the-last-12) y los números ya son más aproximados a los que se muestran en la página de inicio de SOes. La diferencia se debe a los datos en SEDE se renuevan periodicamente.

[image: Estadísticas en SEDE]

[image: Estadísticas en SOes]

El cambio fue modificar las últimas dos cláusulas `where ParentId is null`  y `where ParentId is not null` por `where PostTypeId = 1` y `where PostTypeId = 2` los cuales corresponden a preguntas y respuestas respectivamente

Comment: Las cifras no me cuadran - puede ser por los días de corte -, pero he modificado para hacer el query con `PostTypeId` y ahora los datos coinciden con los que sugiere @jachguate

Comment: @JuanK: Puede ser que no cuadren por otros "detalles". Me pregunto si el query al que me refería podría ser un ejemplo para tema acerca de lo que es popular no necesariamente es correcto.