# SEDE: Bug que lleva a confusión sobre estadísticas de SOes

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, data-explorer

## En breve

Al acceder a queries en SEDE se muestra en la parte superior el favicon de SOes y en switch sites el favicon de meta SOes, o viceversa, cuando debería ser el mismo el que se mostrara en ambos.

Hay un bug porque al menos hay dos queries distintos en los que pasa lo mismo.

## Caso 1

En relación a la conmemoración del primer mes de SOes y quise revisar las estadísticas así que visité Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) por primera vez en los últimos meses.

En la página se inicio de SEDE se indica los siguientes números

[image: Stack Overflow en español en página de inicio de SEDE]

De ahí le dí click y navegando los queries destacados dí con [Total Questions and Answers per Month for the last 12](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/6134/total-questions-and-answers-per-month-for-the-last-12), el cual me mostró lo siguiente:

[image: Total Questions and Answers per Month for the last 12]

Recorté la gráfica y la subí a [mi respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350/65) a [La problemática de los temas en SOes y la inactividad del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348/la-problem%C3%A1tica-de-los-temas-en-soes-y-la-inactividad-del-sitio). Gracias un comentario de JuanK me parcaté de que algo raro ocurre.

Cerca de la esquina superior derecha se muestra el log de SOes,

[image: Compose query]

Pero justo abajo del query se muestra el logo de Meta de SOes

[image: Switch sites]

## Caso 2

JuanK nos comparte un query en [su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387/65) a [Número de preguntas y respuestas por mes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386/n%C3%BAmero-de-preguntas-y-respuestas-por-mes), pero también ocurre algo extraño.

El siguiente URL incluye /es/ de lo cual infiero que los números corresponden a SOes.

http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/424312/number-of-questions-and-answers-per-month-in-a-given-yyyy-mm-range?start=%272015%2F10%27%20&end=%272016%2F01%27

[image: es]

El siguiente URL incluye /esme/ de lo cual infiero que los números corresponden a Meta de SOes.

http://data.stackexchange.com/esme/query/424312/number-of-questions-and-answers-per-month-in-a-given-yyyy-mm-range?start=%272015%2F10%27+&end=%272016%2F01%27

[image: esme]

## Referencias

- [Un mes de beta publico - ¿ahora qué?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374/un-mes-de-beta-publico-ahora-qu%C3%A9)

Comment: Se realizó un cambio mayor luego de leer http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386/n%C3%BAmero-de-preguntas-y-respuestas-por-mes la cual fue publicada unos momentos antes que la versión inicial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No creo que se trate de un bug, pero definitivamente es algo que confunde bastante.

Ya hubo quien lo comentó en [Color of site icons on Stack Exchange Data Explorer is (not technically incorrect but) confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169397/209901), esto es, *El color del icono de los sitios en Stack Exchange Data Explorer es (no técnicamente incorrecto pero) confuso*.

En efecto, el icono muestra el sitio al que te lleva el botón "Switch sites", por lo que no muestra el icono del sitio en el que estás sino el otro. Es decir, en el sitio principal mostrará el de Meta y viceversa.

Por tanto, parece que no es bug sino un diseño... raro.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sospecho es que es un Bug de esme pareciera que los datos del meta los esta intercambiando con los del sitio principal.

Aunque analizándolo más de fondo parece un tema de usabilidad más que un bug.

He actualizado mi post relacionado con los resultados que considero correctos.  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387/65

Comment: De acuerdo. Justo recién hice un cambio mayor a la pregunta.